# Populating a Modal contact form on click with javascript

Tags: forms, modal-dialog, contacts

I have a modal form which loads upon clicking an anchor tag with a specific class.

What I am trying to achieve is to apply a value to a certain text field within the mdoal form when the anchor tag is clicked.

I have this function working to a point with the following, when the anchor tag is clicked the input field with the id="contact-catalogue" is populated with the value set within anchor tag:

```
<input type="text" id="contact-catalogue" />

<a class="button-left contact" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contact-catalogue').value='link2';">Request</a></div>
```

My problem is that the modal form loads when the anchor tag is clicked and the value set within the anchor tag does not populate the required text field.

My guess is that because the form loads after anchor tag is clicked there is no ID being picked up and that is why the value is not being passed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have come up with a solution on how to populate the input field within the Modal form upon the onclick event.

Basically I set a delay on the onclick event which gives the modal window enough time to load. This allows the onclick event to find the ID of the inputfield within the form and populate it with the value that I require:

```
<a class="button-left contact" onclick="setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('contact-catalogue').value='AS101'}, 1000);" href="#">Kit Insert Request</a></div>
```

I hope this helps anyone in a simialr situation in the future.